# Mark the statements below that must be true

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This is a homework question and I was wondering what would you do to determine if a statement is true. I have already solved the first part of the question

$w  = 2x-4y $

I have a screenshot with two of the choices as I want to solve the rest by myself. I know that the span is the set consisting of all linear combinations of some vectors but I am completely lost about what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that z is a linear combination of x and y and then calculating w= 2x- 4y shows that w is also a linear combination of x and y.  We can replace z in Span(y,z) with a linear combination of x and y so, yes, Span(y,z)= Span(x,y).   Similarly we can replace w in Span(w,y) with a linear combination of x and y so Span(w,y)= Span(x,y)= Span(y,z)= Span(x,y,z).